# Filtering with Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have an application with several Web API controllers and I now I have a requirement which is to be able to filter GET results by the object properties. I've been looking at using [OData](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/asp-net-core-odata-now-available/) but I'm not sure if it's a good fit for a couple reasons:

1. The Web API controller does not have direct access to the `DataContext`, instead it gets data from our database through our "domain" layer so it has no visibility into our Entity Framework models.
2. Tying into the first item, the Web API deals with lightweight DTO model objects which are produced in the domain layer. This is effectively what hides the EF models. The issue here is I want these queries to be executed in our database but by the time the Web API method gets a collection from the domain layer all of the objects in the collection have been mapped to these DTO objects, so I don't see how the OData filter could possibly do it's job when the objects are once-removed from EF in this way.
3. This item may be the most important one: We don't really want to allow arbitrary querying against our Web API/Database. We just sort of want to *leverage* this OData library to avoid writing our own filters, and filter parsers/builders for every type of object that could be returned by one of our Web API endpoints.

Am I on the wrong track based on #3? If not, would we be able to use this OData library without significant refactoring to how our Web API and our EF interact?

Comment: As I understand this, OData allows you to pass in a 'query' to a web service endpoint and receive a dataset. However, you want to filter data between your Web API controller and your domain layer. Why not pass LINQ Expression to your domain layer? If the models are not 1:1, you can translate via mapper.

Comment: you query into yr Dao's, and then in a service you map them to Dto's

Comment: but if yr good with getting all items out of the db and then query against it, that's a performance issue. also create some kind of Filter object.

Comment: @alans that sounds like it could work, but how do I get that LINQ expression to pass to the domain layer in the first place? Can I take it from the OData URL query somehow?

Comment: @KyleV. You're going to have to explain your infrastructure a bit more in detail. Are we talking about a service-to-service call? If so, do you have a particular IPC in place? Or is the domain layer just a separate assembly from your Web API controllers? And so on...

Comment: @KyleV.Btw, when you asked that question about the query in the URL, I'm starting to realize that you are trying to pass a filter from a GET request to a Web API, then pass that filter to your domain layer. This is not going to be pretty for the reasons StevePy mentioned. But the least painful way is you can use OData against your DTO, then use a mapper from DTO to your domain models. Also, in this case, AutoMapper is your friend.

Comment: @alans Yes that's essentially what I'm doing. My Web API controller and the domain layer are in separate assemblies. If I do what you suggested and do `OData -> DTO -> AutoMappter -> EF Model -> Database` would that work in such a way that the filtering is done in the Database still? Or would the mapping part break that?

Comment: @KyleV. What Automapper will be mapping is the OData Expression being passed to EF. So, on the domain model, it will get Expression and EF will translate that Expression into SQL and do its thing.

Comment: @alans So I'll be giving Automapper the OData Expression? Sorry, I don't understand, could you explain?

Comment: @KyleV. Maybe that might be too much coding. But here's a simpler idea: From your domain layer, you return a DTO `IQueryable` via Automapper's [Queryable Extension](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html). Then, you use OData's ODataQueryOptions's ApplyTo to the IQueryable DTO. Then get your results from there.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had experience with OData, but from what I can see it's designed to be fed a Context and manages the interaction and returning of those models. I am definitely not a fan of returning Entities in any form to a client.

It's an ugly situation to be in, but when faced with this, my first course of action is to push back to the clients to justify their searching needs. The default request is almost always "Well, it would be nice to be able to search against everything."  My answer to that is that I don't want to know what you want, I want to know what you need because I don't want to give you a loaded gun to shoot your own foot off with and then have you blame me because the system came grinding to a halt. Searching is a huge performance killer if it's too open-ended. It's hard to test for accuracy/relevance, and efficiently index for 100% of possible search cases when users only *need* 25% of those scenarios.  If the client cannot tell you what searching they will need, and just want everything because they *might* need it, then they don't need it yet.

Personally I stick to specific search DTOs and translate those into the linq expressions.

If I was faced with a hard requirement to implement something like that, I would:

1. Try to push for these searches/reports to be done off a reporting replica that is synchronized with the live database. (To minimize the bleeding when some idiot managers fire up some wacky non-indexed search criteria so that it doesn't tie up the production DB where people are trying to do work.)
2. Create a new bounded DbContext specific for searching with separate entity definitions that only expose the minimum # of properties to represent search criteria and IDs.
3. Hook this bounded context into the API and OData. It will return "search results". When a user selects a search result, use the ID(s) against the API to load the applicable domain, or initiate an action, etc.

no. 1. is optional, a nice to have provided they can live with searches not "seeing" updated criteria until replicated. (I.e. a few seconds to minutes depending on replication strategy/size) Normally these searches are used for reporting-type queries so I'd push to keep these separate from the normal day-to-day searching options that users use. (I.e. an advanced search option or the like.)

Comment: When you stick to specific search DTOs how do you then design your Web API endpoints to filter based on one or more properties of one of those DTOs? I don't know how to express a search criteria and that's something that OData takes care of with its `http://localhost:5000/odata/Books?$filter=Price le 50` query syntax.

Comment: The specific DTOs apply when the client lays out the specific search scenarios. I.e. the user picks a scenario, with applicable parameters if any. I.e. from an Orders screen they can search by order # or a search like "Orders Past Due". Basically what are the useful scenarios for the user. For more open-ended searching (think of your gt/gte/lt/lte AND/OR/NOT pick your field etc.) with query expressions, this more advanced option would involve using something like OData or custom filtering. My main push is to keep that kind of searching away from day-to-day usage.